# Rapidxml causing a "Stack Smashing detected" error when calling next_sibling()

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

So, I'm parsing this xml:

```
<layout>
    <elements>
        <first>
            <x>centered</x>
            <y>300</y>
            <text>Button</text>
            <function>toggleOption</function>
        </first>
        <second>no</second>
    </elements>

</layout>
```

It's being parsed by the *rapidxml* library. Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
doc.parse<0>(big_buffer);

rapidxml::xml_node<>* element_ptr = doc.first_node("layout")->first_node("elements")->first_node();

while(element_ptr){
    printf("FOUND: '%s'\n", element_ptr->name());

    element_ptr = element_ptr->next_sibling();
}
```

Running this causes:

```
FOUND: 'first'
FOUND: 'second'
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./program terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I followed the pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169943/c-rapidxml-get-sibling-of-the-same-type), but the problem is `element_ptr` doesn't have a `next_sibling()`. No biggy, but the fact the `element_ptr->next_sibling()` causes a crash is no fun.

Comment: After more investigation, I've found that the problem occurs when one sibling node, in this case "first", has any child nodes.

Comment: A small self-contained example is required. I use this approach regularly and have no issues. The problem is likely elsewhere...